# Can not combine 2 date range queries in Elasticsearch object syntax

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I want to search a document in a way that I filter it by exact values for the "from" and "to" fields. I use DateRangeQuery objects that I pass to the bool query instance.

This filter works fine when its only one date being filtered, but when both are active it returns no documents at all. Code bellow

```
  DateRangeQuery fromDateRangeQuery = new DateRangeQuery()
        {
            Name = "from_query",
            Field = "from",
            GreaterThanOrEqualTo = dateFrom,
            LessThanOrEqualTo = dateFrom,
        };
        queryContainers.Add(fromDateRangeQuery);

        DateRangeQuery ToDateRangeQuery = new DateRangeQuery()
        {
            Name = "to_query",
            Field = "to",
            GreaterThanOrEqualTo = dateTo,
            LessThanOrEqualTo = dateTo,
        };
        queryContainers.Add(ToDateRangeQuery);
        //more terms filters not related to the 2 fields 
        var searchRequest = new SearchRequest("0___aggregate_");
        searchRequest.SearchType = SearchType.QueryThenFetch;
        searchRequest.From = 0;
        searchRequest.Size = 10000;
        searchRequest.Query = boolQuery;

        var searchResponse = Get().SearchAsync<AggregationHolder>(searchRequest);
        searchResponse.Wait(60000);

        var status = searchResponse.Result;
```

Both dateFrom and dateTo are regular date time object. What am I doing wrong, why cant I combine these 2 filters?

Comment: Please add the raw elastic query generated by the above code.

Comment: Why do you have `LessThanOrEqualTo` in your `fromDateRangeQuery` query and also why do you have `GreaterThanOrEqualTo` in your `ToDateRangeQuery` query? Have you tried by removing them?

Comment: @OpsterESNinjaNishant How do I do that

Comment: @MuzafferGalata I have a from and to date field that I know the precise values of. I need to search for them to match a specific date not a range

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, the problem is your date format. Could you please try like below?

```
ElasticClient elasticClient = new ElasticClient(new ConnectionSettings(
    new Uri(connString))
    .RequestTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))
    .DefaultIndex(defaultIndexName)
);
DateRangeQuery queryFrom = new DateRangeQuery()
{
    Name = "from_query",
    Field = "from",
    GreaterThanOrEqualTo = "05/12/2020 01:03:15",
    LessThanOrEqualTo = "05/12/2020 01:03:16",
    Format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
};
DateRangeQuery queryTo = new DateRangeQuery()
{
    Name = "to_query",
    Field = "to",
    GreaterThanOrEqualTo = "05/12/2020 11:20:32",
    LessThanOrEqualTo = "05/12/2020 11:20:33",
    Format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
};
QueryContainer queryMain = queryFrom & queryTo;

ISearchResponse<AggregationHolder> searchResponse = elasticClient.Search<AggregationHolder>(s => s
    .RequestConfiguration(r => r.DisableDirectStreaming())
    .From(0)
    .Size(100)
    .Query(q2 => q2
        .Bool(b => b
        .Should(queryMain))
    )
);
```